# In QGIS, in the print composer screen if you save you work as 'Save as template' how do you reload it?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have various data that I am using in the print composer to create images and putting them into word. They will be marked soon by my assessor and I will likely go back and improve them, how do I re-access them?

Comment: Seems to be related to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179998/how-to-import-a-composer-template-into-qgis-print-composer/192638#192638)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **create** for each output image a own composer. For example you can **duplicate** the composer and manage everything over the **Composer Manager**. That way you can open them later again and improve details.

[image: qgis composer]

For further detais check the [**QGIS documentation for the Print Composer**](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html#first-steps).

---

*The template option is just used to have the basic settings saved. You can save the layout as template and load it again in another session by clicking on `Add Items from Template`.*