# Importing Composer Template into QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, import, template

How can I import a `.qpt`-file into Print Composer (Composer Manager) in QGIS? I've tried saving it in the composer_templates folder but to no avail.

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using, can you add a screen capture showing what you've tried in the Composer Manager?

Comment: I'm using QGIS Lyon, sorry how do you add a screenshot?

Comment: @DCourt - When composing a question/answer, there's a row of icons above the text box, such as **Bolding** or _Italicising_ text. 6 icons from the right is the "Image" icon which allows you to upload image files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add **items** from a template by creating a new print composer and selecting the option shown in the image:

[image: Add items from template]

Then select your template and it should load up all the items you created.

Comment: @DCourt - Most welcome buddy! Glad it was helpful =)

Answer (score 4):

I think there a another way.

select composer manager

[image: select composer manager]

then you have

[image: manager composer manager]

instead of "composseur vide" you should have "empty composer"

So you click and select "specific".

Click on "..."

Name you new composer.

Comment: To me this is the more appropriate method, as it includes page size and guides (and possilbly much more). The other answer suggests "Add items from template", but indeed this only adds the items.

Answer (score 0):

From the [QGIS docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html#the-layout-manager):

> Drag-and-drop a print layout template .qpt file from any file browser
> onto the map canvas or double-click it in the Browser panel generates
> a new print layout from the template.